# Convert Type to myType

Tags: c#, reflection, types, casting

I want to set default values for all `decimal` fields in `Object`. Method that does it looks like this:

```
private Type SetAllFieldsAsDefault(Type register)
{
    var fields = register.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (var field in fields)
    {
        if (field.FieldType != typeof(double)) continue;
        field.SetValue(field, 0);
    }
    return register;
}
```

After I try casting to `myType`, but it does not work

```
myType = (MyType )SetAllFieldsAsDefault(myType.GetType());
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You're not giving it the actual object to set values into and you're only returning a `Type`. It cannot be cast into the actual object you have. `SetValue` should have the actual object as the first argument.

Comment: I don't know what this code expects to do.  You can't set instance values on a type.  And `field.SetValue(field, 0)` is simply wrong.  See [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6z33zd7h(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an object as input and as output

```
 private object SetAllFieldsAsDefault(object _register)
 {
      Type register = _register.GetType();
```

and you'll set its values in the above method

```
      field.SetValue(_register, 0);
```

Finally chain the modified input

```
return _register;
}
```

calling the method

```
myType = (MyType)SetAllFieldsAsDefault(myType);
```

Here is a [test online](http://ideone.com/tbR0dq)

```
public static void Main()
{
    var myType = new MyType();
    Console.WriteLine(myType.one + " " + myType.two);
    Console.WriteLine("before");
    myType = SetAllFieldsAsDefault(myType) as MyType;
    Console.WriteLine("after");
    Console.WriteLine(myType.one + " " + myType.two);
}

class MyType {
    internal double one = -1.1;
    internal string test = "hi";
    internal double two = 3.3;
}
```

the output is

```
before
-1.1 3.3
after
0 0
```